# Is it always beneficial to use return_sequences=True for time series prediction with RNN?

Tags: time-series, lstm, rnn

I roughly understand what `return_sequences=True`  does when being used for time series prediction with RNN (each RNN cell outputs its hidden state). Now my question is it always advisable to use `return_sequences=True`  for a conventional RNN or a LSTM? What are the pros and cons of using it?

**Reminder**: Would anybody mind sharing his/her experience on that topic. Do you usually use it or not? I'll appreciate every comment.

Comment: Using `return_sequences=True` is a matter of whether in your specific problem you need the whole sequence of predictions or just the final step, not something _beneficial_.

Comment: I agree with @noe.  From limited personal experience, return the sequences when you want to use further RNN/LSTM layers, but drop down to a single output before moving on to dense layers.

Comment: Thanks all for your answer. To be totally honest I have to admit that I do not really undestand it. As far as I understand return_sequence= True returns the sequence for every note of the RNN/LSTM and thus you have more training data to learn the mapping between inputs and outputs. You also have to adjust the training data if return_sequence =True to have more samples for the input output mapping of a neural network.

Comment: @noe: Any comments to my last comment. I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.